# Opencart Theme - Changing colour of table header using CSS?

Tags: css, opencart, css-tables

Just wondering if you could assist me please, I'm currently building a site for a client using Opencart (Version 2.3.0.2) and I have the SELLMORE theme installed. themeforest.net/item/sellmore-highly-customizable-multipurpose-opencart-theme/19916292

I'm really struggling to make sense of how I go about changing the background colour on a table in the product description section? Everything I have tried doesn’t seem to work, I’d like the first row to have a green or black background and the rest of the rows to be normal. I don’t know where to change the settings/CSS or in the CSS of the header.tpl file as advised by the author? (please see attached for what I would like to achieve)

The author has advised me to go to: catalog\view\theme\sellmore\template\common\header.twig (the lines 121-127) but offer any actual help beyond that, **I'm not the most technical, hence the post.**

I'm none the wiser of what needs changing, please see an example of what I'm trying to achieve here:

[image: Example]

***Please see code below:***

```php
/*  Wrapper  */
<?php if($t1d_wrapper_frame_bg_color_status =='1') { ?>
.wrapper.framed, .wrapper.full-width {
    background-color: <?php echo $t1d_wrapper_frame_bg_color; ?>;
}
<?php } ?>
<?php if($t1d_wrapper_frame_bg_color_status =='1') { ?>
.wrapper.full-width-border {border: 50px solid <?php echo $t1d_wrapper_frame_bg_color; ?>;}
<?php } else { ?>
.wrapper.full-width-border {border: 50px solid transparent;}
<?php } ?>
<?php if($t1d_wrapper_shadow =='1') { ?>
.wrapper.framed {box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);}
<?php } ?>
<?php if($t1d_boxes_shadow =='1') { ?>
.wrapper.boxed #column-left .panel, .wrapper.boxed #column-right .panel, .wrapper.boxed #content {box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);}
<?php } ?>

/*  Content Column  */
#content, #content .panel, .category-list + .panel-default > .panel-heading, #search .form-control, #search .input-group-addon, #search .input-group-addon .btn, #livesearch_search_results, .modal-content, .alert-success, .alert-info, .cookie-message, .custom_box, .panel-inline-items, .theme-lookbook-bg, .theme-banner-bg, .theme-gallery-bg, .theme-store-tv-bg, .highly-recommended-module-content, #tab-review .rating-text {
    background-color: <?php echo $t1d_content_column_bg_color; ?>;
}
.tab-content .table-bordered, .tab-content .table-bordered > thead > tr > th, .tab-content .table-bordered > tbody > tr > th, .tab-content .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > th, .tab-content .table-bordered > thead > tr > td, .tab-content .table-bordered > tbody > tr > td, .tab-content .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > td {
    border-color: <?php echo $t1d_content_column_bg_color; ?>;
}
.well, .table-bordered, .table-bordered > thead > tr > th, .table-bordered > tbody > tr > th, .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > th, .table-bordered > thead > tr > td, .table-bordered > tbody > tr > td, .table-bordered > tfoot > tr > td, .table-bordered img {
    border: 1px solid <?php echo $t1d_content_column_bg_color; ?>;
    background-color: <?php echo $t1d_content_column_hli_bg_color; ?>;
}
<?php if($t1d_content_column_hli_buy_column ==1) { ?>
.product-buy .product-buy-wrapper {
    background-color: <?php echo $t1d_content_column_hli_bg_color; ?>;
    padding: 30px;
}
<?php } ?>
.nav-tabs > li > a, .nav-tabs > li > a:hover, .sitemap > ul > li > a, .manufacturer-list h3, .search-panel, .product-page #product-tabs .tab-content, .contact-details-wrapper {
    background-color: <?php echo $t1d_content_column_hli_bg_color; ?>;
}

#livesearch_search_results li, .modal-footer, .list-group a, .list-group a.active, .list-group a.active:hover, .list-group a:hover, a.list-group-item.active, a.list-group-item.active:hover, a.list-group-item.active:focus {
    border-top: 1px solid <?php echo $t1d_content_column_separator_color; ?>;   
}   
.modal-header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid <?php echo $t1d_content_column_separator_color; ?>;    
}
.contact-map, .img-thumbnail-theme {
    border: 1px solid <?php echo $t1d_content_column_separator_color; ?>;   
}
hr, #search .input-group-addon {
    border-color: <?php echo $t1d_content_column_separator_color; ?>;
}
```

As requested the actual code from the page:

```html
<p><b>Finish:</b> White (RAL 9010)<br><b>Base Material:</b> Aluminium<br><b>Fitting:</b> 15mm thread (1/2")<br><b>Type:</b> Vertical Designer Radiator<br><b>Manufacturers Guarantee:</b> 10 Years<br><b>Delivery: <font color="#16B778">Free UK Home Delivery</font></b></p><table class="table table-bordered"><tbody><tr><td align="center"><b><style="background-color: rgb(255,="" 255,="" 0);"=""><span style="background-color: inherit;">Height (mm)</span><br></style="background-color:></b></td><td align="center"><b>Width (mm)</b><br></td><td align="center"><b>Depth (mm)</b><br></td><td align="center"><b>Watts</b><br></td><td align="center"><b>BTU's</b><br></td></tr><tr><td align="center">1446<br></td><td align="center">260<br></td><td align="center">95<br></td><td align="center">735<br></td><td align="center">2508<br></td></tr><tr><td align="center">1446<br></td><td align="center">340<br></td><td align="center">95<br></td><td align="center">980<br></td><td align="center">3344<br></td></tr><tr><td align="center">1446<br></td><td align="center">420<br></td><td align="center">95<br></td><td align="center">1225<br></td><td align="center">4180<br></td></tr><tr><td align="center">1446<br></td><td align="center">500<br></td><td align="center">95<br></td><td align="center">1470<br></td><td align="center">5016<br></td></tr><tr><td align="center">1846<br></td><td align="center">260<br></td><td align="center">95<br></td><td align="center">891<br></td><td align="center">3040<br></td></tr><tr><td align="center">1846<br></td><td align="center">340<br></td><td align="center">95<br></td><td align="center">1188<br></td><td align="center">4053<br></td></tr><tr><td align="center">1846<br></td><td align="center">420<br></td><td align="center">95<br></td><td align="center">1485<br></td><td align="center">5067<br></td></tr><tr><td align="center">1846<br></td><td align="center">500<br></td><td align="center">95<br></td><td align="center">1782<br></td><td align="center">6080<br></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Can you post the code of the table to see what clasess do it use?? and btw the php code can't be tested on the snippet

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the response, I've now added the code from the page.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in your CSS there's propierties for the head of the table but then in the code you dont specify where's the head you just used `<tbody>` for the hole table.

The code you posted about CSS is with PHP and the HTML you posted is a little bit dirty in one line so all i'm saying are speculations because I can't test it.

But the answer could be to use `<thead>` for the row you want to be the head of the table. So the code will look like this.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Height (mm) </th>
            <th> Width (mm) </th>
            ...
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Try this and tell me if you can solve it :)
Hope it helps you.